# Relatorios , Duvida com somas e datas

Tags: vb.net, microsoft-access

por alguns dias tenho tido um pequeno problema onde a cliente nos solicitou uma alteração em um relatório que temos no nosso sistema escrito em VB.NET
Basicamente, Filtro a minha DataGridView, e através dela vou montando o relatório,

Com este código faço o filtro.

```
 Dim cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim Da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim Dt As New DataTable
    Dim dtinicio As String
    Dim dtfim As String
    dtinicio = mskdtcomeco.Text
    dtfim = mskdtfinal.Text
    datainicio3 = mskdtcomeco.Text
    datafim3 = mskdtfinal.Text

    cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Firebird.mdb"
    cn.Open()
    mskdtcomeco.Text = CDate(mskdtcomeco.Text).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
    mskdtfinal.Text = CDate(mskdtfinal.Text).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
    Try
        With cmd
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtInicio", dtinicio)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtFim", dtfim)
            .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM OS WHERE data between @dtInicio And @dtFim  And NOMEFUNCIONARIO = '" & ComboBox2.Text & "' ORDER BY data"
            .Connection = cn
        End With

        With Da
            .SelectCommand = cmd
            Dt = New DataTable
            .Fill(Dt)
            OSDataGridViewFuncionario.DataSource = Dt

        End With

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    cmd.Parameters.Clear()
    Dim linha As DataGridViewRow

    Dim valor As Double
    Dim valor2 As Double
    Dim valor3 As Double

    For Each linha In OSDataGridViewFuncionario.Rows
        valor = valor + linha.Cells(5).Value ' 
        valor2 = valor2 + linha.Cells(6).Value '
        valor3 = valor3 + linha.Cells(4).Value
    Next
    lbltotfunc.Text = FormatCurrency(valor)
    LBLSALAO.Text = FormatCurrency(valor2)
    lbltotal.Text = FormatCurrency(valoe3)
```

Depois dos resultados listados no DG, vem a impressão.

```
    Private Sub pdFuncionario_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles pdFuncionario.PrintPage
    Dim g As Graphics = e.Graphics
    Dim Cliente As String = String.Empty
    Dim funcionario As String = String.Empty
    Dim servico As String = String.Empty
    Dim totservico As String = String.Empty
    Dim remum As String = String.Empty
    Dim data As String = String.Empty
    Dim PosicaoLinha As Integer = 40
    Dim LinhasPorPagina As Byte = 45
    'Definições da pagina
    g.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Millimeter
    'Desenhar folha
    Dim Titulo As New Font("Times New Roman", 8, FontStyle.Regular Or FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Millimeter)

    g.DrawString("Relatorio de Funcionario ", Titulo, Brushes.Black, 65, 7)


    'Ler datagridview
    For L = 0 To LinhasPorPagina - 1
        If LinhaAtual = OSDataGridViewFuncionario.Rows.Count Then Continue For
        For i As Integer = 0 To OSDataGridViewFuncionario.ColumnCount - 9

            If Not OSDataGridViewFuncionario.Item(i, LinhaAtual).Value = Nothing Then
                Cliente = OSDataGridViewFuncionario.Item(i, LinhaAtual).Value

            End If

        Next
        For o As Integer = 0 To OSDataGridViewFuncionario.ColumnCount - 8
            If Not OSDataGridViewFuncionario.Item(o, LinhaAtual).Value = Nothing Then
                funcionario = OSDataGridViewFuncionario.Item(o, LinhaAtual).Value

            End If
        Next
        For u As Integer = 0 To OSDataGridViewFuncionario.ColumnCount - 6
            If Not OSDataGridViewFuncionario.Item(u, LinhaAtual).Value = Nothing Then
                servico = OSDataGridViewFuncionario.Item(u, LinhaAtual).Value

            End If
        Next
        For a As Integer = 0 To OSDataGridViewFuncionario.ColumnCount - 4
            If Not OSDataGridViewFuncionario.Item(a, LinhaAtual).Value = Nothing Then
                totservico = OSDataGridViewFuncionario.Item(a, LinhaAtual).Value

            End If
        Next

        For c As Integer = 0 To OSDataGridViewFuncionario.ColumnCount - 2

            If Not OSDataGridViewFuncionario.Item(c, LinhaAtual).Value = Nothing Then

                data = OSDataGridViewFuncionario.Item(c, LinhaAtual).Value


            End If

        Next



        'Desenhar conteudo na página
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Cliente", New Font("Verdana", 6), Brushes.Black, 10, 30)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Cliente, New Font("Verdana", 6), Brushes.Black, 9, PosicaoLinha)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Funcionario", New Font("Verdana", 6), Brushes.Black, 55, 30)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(funcionario, New Font("Verdana", 6), Brushes.Black, 55, PosicaoLinha)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Serviço", New Font("Verdana", 6), Brushes.Black, 90, 30)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(servico, New Font("Verdana", 6), Brushes.Black, 90, PosicaoLinha)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Valor Recebido", New Font("Verdana", 6), Brushes.Black, 130, 30)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("R$ " & totservico, New Font("Verdana", 6), Brushes.Black, 134, PosicaoLinha)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Data", New Font("Verdana", 6), Brushes.Black, 190, 30)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(data, New Font("Verdana", 6), Brushes.Black, 180, PosicaoLinha)


        PosicaoLinha += 5
        LinhaAtual += 1
        Cliente = String.Empty
        funcionario = String.Empty
        servico = String.Empty
        totservico = String.Empty
        remum = String.Empty
        data = String.Empty

    Next
    'Se linha atual for igual á linhas devidas por página então muda de página
    If LinhaAtual < OSDataGridViewFuncionario.Rows.Count Then
        e.HasMorePages = True
    Else
        e.HasMorePages = False
        PosicaoLinha = PosicaoLinha + 5
        e.Graphics.DrawString("______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________", New Font("Verdana", 8), Brushes.Black, 0, PosicaoLinha)
        PosicaoLinha = PosicaoLinha + 5
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Data Inicial do Relatorio: " & datainicio3 & "                                   Data Final do Relatorio  : " & datafim3, New Font("Verdana", 8), Brushes.Black, 20, PosicaoLinha)
        PosicaoLinha = PosicaoLinha + 2
        e.Graphics.DrawString("__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________", New Font("Verdana", 8), Brushes.Black, 0, PosicaoLinha)
        PosicaoLinha = PosicaoLinha + 5
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Funcionario: " & ComboBox2.Text, New Font("Verdana", 12), Brushes.Black, 20, PosicaoLinha)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Valor a Receber: ", New Font("Verdana", 12), Brushes.Black, 135, PosicaoLinha)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(lbltotfunc.Text, New Font("Verdana", 12), Brushes.Black, 175, PosicaoLinha)
    End If
End Sub
```

Assim, quando a cliente faz uma busca com um intervalo de datas Ex : 10/05/2015 - 20/05/2015, o relatório apenas mostra os valores totais,

gostaria de saber se teria alguma forma ,de criar um total para cada dia neste relatório, que quando passar a linha para próxima data somar os valores diários , para que ela n possa ficar filtrando dia por dia... 
desde de já agradeço a atenção e colaboração de todos. obrigado.

Comment: Você faz questão que esses totais por dia saiam no mesmo relatório, ou pode ser um relatório diferente?

Comment: a cliente me pediu que apareça o total dos dias no relatório geral , pode ser um relatório diferente.. mas que ela consiga tirar com um intervalo entre datas, e que saia o valor por dia quando passar de uma data a outra. porem não tenho nem ideia de como fazer isso.

Comment: No print que você mandou agora pouco você trouxe a coluna de valor sem o `SUM` o qual o @ctgPi tinha indicado, existe algum motivo?

Comment: pois tentei `SUM(VALORSERVICO) AS total`  , e nada retornou ao DG alem das DATAS agrupadas...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar: nunca, nunca, **nunca** construa consultas SQL concatenando strings a menos que você saiba exatamente o que você está fazendo. Faça isso:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtInicio", dtinicio)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtFim", dtfim)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nomeFuncionario", ComboBox2.Text)
.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM OS WHERE data between @dtInicio And @dtFim And NOMEFUNCIONARIO = @nomeFuncionario ORDER BY data"
```

Pra gerar o valor agregado por dia, você pode alterar a consulta SQL para algo tipo (note o GROUP BY)

```
SELECT data, SUM(coluna_valores) AS total
FROM OS
WHERE data between @dtInicio And @dtFim AND
      NOMEFUNCIONARIO = @nomeFuncionario
GROUP BY data
ORDER BY data
```

Isso vai te dar uma resposta como

```
    data    | total
------------+-------
 2015-06-05 | 3500
 2015-06-08 | 1700
 2015-06-09 | 700
```

que você teria que alguma forma ou integrar no seu relatório atual ou usar pra gerar um novo relatório.

Comment: Se a data dele possuir horas vai dar problema, não?

Comment: Certo, consegui gerar como no exemplo, porem há alguma forma de na coluna Serviços da minha DG, eu incluir todos os serviços do dia?